# Ruby regular expression for conditional expression

Tags: ruby, regex, conditional-statements

I need to write a regular expression for lines of expression such as these:

```
constraint :name, 'name != nil'
constraint :name, 'name =~/^[A-Z]/'
constraint :age, 'age >= 0'
```

A line always contains the word "constraint :", and any word can come after ":" followed by ",".

A conditional expression will then appear inside ' '.

I have written a regex like this:

```
/^constraint :(\w*),'(.*)'$/
```

And it doesn't match. I am new to Ruby and regular expression. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can the contain single quotes? You're going down a slippery slope here. What's the ultimate purpose?

Comment: It is single quotes that are in the lines. These lines are given in my assignment. I have to be able to extract what the line says in these lines to be able to create a new class dynamically and add attributes with the given constraints.

Comment: @DaveNewton In any case, it seems that the constraint's name cannot contain single quotes, and the constraint value cannot contain a new line... In which case `'.*'$` should capture it.

Comment: I'm asking if the constraint itself, the string with the regex, can contain a single quote. I still don't quite understand the purpose of the exercise-this seems like more of an exercise in metaprogramming than something you'd use regular expressions for.

Comment: No, the regex itself does not contain a single quote. A line represents a constraint to a class attribute. This assignment is about code generation (creating a class dynamically) from a text file that contains information about a class, attributes, constraints on attributes. This is my first Ruby program that I write, and the assignment is given by my course teacher, so I cannot really explain the ultimate purpose of the exercise either. So excuse me if I fail to express terms and thoughts behind the program. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the space after the comma.
Try `/^constraint :(\w*), '(.*)'$/`

Although to be more general, I'd go with this: `/^constraint :([^,]+),\s*'(.*)'$/`.

Comment: Actually after reading Dave Newton's comment, I think it's even better to use `/^constraint :([^,]+),\s*'(.*)'$/`